# Checking for duplicates in an array using for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am trying to check whether there is any duplicate integer in the user input array. The problem is that the validation of the duplicate does not work properly and I have no idea why it is not showing the desired output. Following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length;
    int arrValue;

    cout << "Enter the length : ";
    cin >> length;

    int *arr = new int[length];

    cout << "Enter " << length << " integers for array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arrValue = arr[i];
    
        for(int k = i + 1; k < length; k++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[k])
            {
                cout << "Duplicate found" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << arrValue << " ";
            }
        }
    }

   delete[] arr;
}
```

**Current result (assuming no duplicate in user input):**

```
Enter the length: 5
Enter 5 integers for array : 5 4 3 2 1
Array : 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2
```

**Expected result (assuming no duplicate in user input):**

```
Enter the length: 5
Enter 5 integers for array : 5 4 3 2 1
Array : 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Current result (assuming duplicate in user input):**

```
Enter the length: 5
Enter 5 integers for array : 5 4 4 2 1
Array : 5 5 5 5 Duplicate found 4 4 3
```

**Expected result (assuming duplicate in user input):**

```
Enter the length: 5
Enter 5 integers for array : 5 4 4 2 1
Array : Duplicate found
```

I believe my loops is the source to the problem. The current result output 10 times and I do not understand why there will be so many same numbers appearing.

Do note that I am trying to apply the validation using loop only and not from C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are printing out each array element *every time* a particular element is not matching another element. It seems that you only want to print out whether *any* duplicate values are found. For this, you can use a `bool` flag to indicate whether any element is duplicated:

```
bool found_dup = false;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    for(int k = i + 1; k < length; k++)
        if(arr[i] == arr[k])
        {
             found_dup = true;
             break;
        }
        //  else: don't print anything yet
```

and then at the end print out the array:

```
if (found_dup)
    std::cout << "Duplicate found";
else
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out to create another validation using bool and this is the closest to what I am looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the program in a more enhanced way (where you don't need to define the length manually - notice the explanation given as comments in code):

```
#include <iostream>    // for input/output operation
#include <vector>      // for dynamic array management
#include <sstream>     // to split the user inputs and assign them to the vector
#include <algorithm>   // to sort the vector
#include <string>      // to work with getline()

// using this statement isn't recommended, but for sake of simplicity
// and avoiding the use of std:: everywhere temporarily (for small programs)
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<int> numbers;
    vector<int> duplicates;
    string input;
    int temp;

    // getting the user input as string
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    stringstream ss(input);

    // splitting the user input string into integers and assigning
    // them into the vector
    while (ss >> temp)
        numbers.push_back(temp);

    // sorting the vector in increasing order
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    // getting the unique numbers (which are not repeated)
    cout << "Unique numbers: ";

    for (size_t i = 0, len = numbers.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (temp == numbers[i])
            // if found a duplicate, then push into the 'duplicates' vector
            duplicates.push_back(temp);
        else
            cout << numbers[i] << ' ';

        temp = numbers[i];
    }

    // getting the duplicates
    cout << "Total duplicates: ";
    for (size_t i = 0, len = duplicates.size(); i < len; i++)
        cout << duplicates[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It'll output something like:

```
Enter the numbers: 1 4 8 9 3 2 3 3 2 1 4 8
Unique numbers: 1 2 3 4 8 9 
Total duplicates: 1 2 3 3 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the if condition to something like this.

```
cout << "Enter the length : ";
    cin >> length;

    int *arr = new int[length];

    cout << "Enter " << length << " integers for array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arrValue = arr[i];
    
        for(int k = i + 1; k < length; k++)
        {
            if(arrValue == arr[k])             //change here.
            {
                cout << "Duplicate found" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << arrValue << " ";
            }
        }
    }

   delete[] arr;
}
```

I would also suggest to use a map data structure. Map allows you to count the frequency of numbers, and thus detect duplicates in linear time.

```
map<int, int> m; // specify the key-value data-type.

for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
{
     m[arr[i]]++;
}

map<int, int>::iterator it; // an iterator to iterate over the datastructure.
for(it = m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
{
     if(it->second>1)             //it->second refers to the value(here, count).
     {
          cout<<it->first<<" ";   //it->first refers to the key.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are actually iterating n-1 times for first element, n-2 times for second element etc., where n is the length of your array. This is why for 5 element array you have printed `5` 4 times.

But generally, if the purpose is to detect duplicates in the array, this strategy is not the best one. Please note that having exemplary array `4 3 4`, with current approach you will correctly detect for the first `4` that the third element is also `4` but once you will move to the third element, it will be marked as ok since it is not checked with the first one element.

You may consider another strategy: create another array of the `n` size. Then iterate through your original array and for each element check if that element is already in the new array. If you detect the presence, you may raise `duplicate` event. Otherwise you can add this element to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're trying to print the same value everytime you find a different one. I got here a solution with one more array that will store the array. It would work too with just one array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length;
    int arrValue;

    cout << "Enter the length : ";
    cin >> length;

    int *arr = new int[length];
    int *noDuplicateArr = new int[length];

    cout << "Enter " << length << " integers for array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    cout << "Array : ";

    bool duplicateFound = false;
    int noDuplicateArrLen = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length && !duplicateFound; i++)
    {
        arrValue = arr[i];

        int k;

        for(k = i + 1; k < length; k++)
        {
            if(arrValue == arr[k])
            {
                duplicateFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (k == length)
            noDuplicateArr[noDuplicateArrLen++] = arrValue;
    }

    if (duplicateFound)
    {
        cout << "Duplicate found";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < noDuplicateArrLen; i++)
        {
            cout << noDuplicateArr[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    delete[] arr;
    delete[] noDuplicateArr;
}
```

Here is the version with just one array:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length;
    int arrValue;

    cout << "Enter the length : ";
    cin >> length;

    int *arr = new int[length];

    cout << "Enter " << length << " integers for array : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    cout << "Array : ";

    bool duplicateFound = false;
    int noDuplicateArrLen = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length && !duplicateFound; i++)
    {
        arrValue = arr[i];

        int k;

        for(k = i + 1; k < length; k++)
        {
            if(arrValue == arr[k])
            {
                duplicateFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (k == length)
            arr[noDuplicateArrLen++] = arrValue;
    }

    if (duplicateFound)
    {
        cout << "Duplicate found";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < noDuplicateArrLen; i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    delete[] arr;
}
```